# cannot run PHP script from apache webserver

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to execute a PHP script from my apache webserver. I tried a Hello World page and it worked, but when I run [this findmyiphone script](https://github.com/albeebe/PHP-FindMyiPhone), it shows 500 error from the webserver. What's wrong?

I tried to execute the `example.php` in terminal by doing `php -f example.php`, how would I do that from a browser in my web server

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read the details of the error. It will tell you what is wrong. We cannot tell you, since only you have access to it.

Comment: in case of linux and apache go to `/var/log/apache2` then `ls -ltr` to sort by newest logs and get your error

Comment: i checked the apache error log but nothing showed up, only access log shows new access

Comment: may be due to php5-curl not installed in your server  ?

Comment: I actually just installed it, just need to restart the apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is I need to restart the server

Comment: glad you made it but the answer is more : install php5-curl and restart apache2 server ...